# iOS 9 APNS token changes after reinstall

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push, token

I have been testing iOS and Push Notifications, and I have noticed that on iOS 9, after every app re-install the APNS token provided by apple has changed. I tested it before, with iOS 7 & 8, and the token remains the same after the app re-install, but on iOS 9 the behavior is different.

I have been testing again with all OS version and I would like to know, if anyone has notice that, or can confirm the new iOS 9 behavior, please.

EDIT: I know that they can change as apple apple says.

Thanks!

Comment: Tokens are made to change, is clearly stated in apple documentations, you should not save them (or you can but just to understand if you need to make a call to the backend to update it)

Comment: Thanks. I know, it can change, Apple say that in the docs, but I mean about the new behavior, I want to try to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I wondered when it would happen.